# What is the corresponding class on iOS which will work same as the Alarm Manager on Android?

Tags: iphone

I am developing an application which schedules messages to post on social media on the iPhone. I have implemented the same for Android using the Alarm Manager.

I have already used `NSTimer` on the iPhone, but it does not run when the application is closed. I also used `LocalNotification` but it needs a user interface that pops up at specific times, and I'd like to perform the action in the background.

What is the best way to implement scheduled tasks on the iPhone when the application is not running so that the task can be performed in the background at a specific time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no public API's for accessing the calendar or alarms.
And local notification is the only way to go.